# UITableView : popViewController and keep row index into parent controller?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have the following config :

A ViewController *parentController* containing a TableView *parentTable* with customized cells to display 2 labels in each of them.

A ViewController *childController* containing a TableView *childTable*. This view is displayed when the user clicks a cell of controllerParent, and childTable content depends on the selected parentController cell.
I use this method :

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controleurEnfant animated:YES];
```

Now when I click a cell in childTable, I come back to my previous view with this :

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Of course I can easily get the index of the childTable's row selected. But the only thing I don't know is how to keep this data to use it in parentController when I come back there ?

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this kind of problem  you can use delegation

Code from [RayWenderlichs Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2):

.h in your childViewController:

```
@class ChildViewController;

@protocol ChildViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)childViewControllerDidSelect:(id)yourData;
@end

@interface childViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ChildViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m in childViewController

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 [self.delegate childViewControllerDidSelect:myObject];
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

in your parentViewController.h adopt the protocol

```
@interface ParentViewController : UITableViewController <ChildViewControllerDelegate>
```

and implement the delegate methods

```
- (void)childViewControllerDidSelect:(id)yourData 
{
    self.someProperty = yourData
}
```

and don't forget to set the delegate before pushing :

```
...
ChildViewController *vc  = [ChildViewController alloc] init];
vc.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Here is some docu about the delegation pattern: [Delegates and Data Sources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html)

Comment: Delegation is the key indeed. This example however seems to be a rather bad fit.

Comment: Ok modified the answer to be less general and more problem specific.